# Ограничение учебной версии - 'Права ролей'

Tags: база-данных, 1с

Установил 1C-8.3.18.1128: Предприятие и 1С Документооборот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открыл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдало ошибку (после 6% загрузки)

При обновлении версии программы возникла ошибка

Достигнуто ограничение учебной версии - 'Права ролей'.

Подскажите как зайти в документооборот (как устранить ошибку).

Лог ошибки

```html
Достигнуто ограничение учебной версии - 'Права ролей'
{ОбщийМодуль.ОбновлениеИнформационнойБазы.Модуль(35)}:  Данные.Записать();
{ОбщийМодуль.УправлениеДоступомСлужебный.Модуль(3585)}:     ОбновлениеИнформационнойБазы.ЗаписатьДанные(ОбъектИлиНаборЗаписей);
{ОбщийМодуль.УправлениеДоступомСлужебный.Модуль(1912)}:         ЗаписатьОбъектИлиНаборЗаписей(Данные, Данные.НаборЗаписей);
{ОбщийМодуль.УправлениеДоступомСлужебный.Модуль(798)}:      ОбновитьНаборЗаписей(ТекущиеДанные, ЕстьИзменения);
{ОбщийМодуль.УправлениеДоступомСлужебный.Модуль(2069)}:             ОбновитьНовыеЗаписиНабораПоРазличнымНовымЗаписям(Данные, Новый Структура, ЕстьИзменения);
{ОбщийМодуль.УправлениеДоступомСлужебный.Модуль(2278)}: ОбновитьНаборыЗаписей(Данные, ЕстьИзменения);
{РегистрСведений.ПраваРолей.МодульМенеджера(56)}:       УправлениеДоступомСлужебный.ОбновитьРегистрСведений(Данные, ЕстьИзменения);
{ОбщийМодуль.УправлениеДоступомСлужебный.Модуль(2831)}: РегистрыСведений.ПраваРолей.ОбновитьДанныеРегистра(ЕстьИзменения);
{РегистрСведений.ПараметрыРаботыПрограммы.МодульМенеджера(769)}:        МодульУправлениеДоступомСлужебный.ОбновитьПараметрыОграниченияДоступа();
{РегистрСведений.ПараметрыРаботыПрограммы.МодульМенеджера(706)}:    ОбновитьПараметрыРаботыПрограммы(СообщитьПрогресс);
{РегистрСведений.ПараметрыРаботыПрограммы.МодульМенеджера(523)}:        ОбновитьПараметрыРаботыПрограммыCУчетомРежимаВыполнения(СообщитьПрогресс);
{(1)}:РегистрыСведений.ПараметрыРаботыПрограммы.ОбработчикДлительнойОперацииОбновленияПараметровРаботыПрограммы(Параметры[0],Параметры[1])
{ОбщийМодуль.ОбщегоНазначения.Модуль(4920)}:    Выполнить ИмяМетода + "(" + ПараметрыСтрока + ")";
{ОбщийМодуль.ДлительныеОперации.Модуль(1026)}:      ОбщегоНазначения.ВыполнитьМетодКонфигурации(ИмяПроцедуры, ПараметрыВызова);
{ОбщийМодуль.ДлительныеОперации.Модуль(1016)}:      ВызватьПроцедуру(ВсеПараметры.ИмяПроцедуры, ВсеПараметры.ПараметрыПроцедуры);

по причине:
Достигнуто ограничение учебной версии - 'Права ролей'
```

Answer (score 0):

Расширьте права. Возможно надо запускать от админа